# noobtus tetris game check valid gird position in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can anyone explain for me why we have to do this function. I read the instruction but I can't figure out why. Site : https://noobtuts.com/unity/2d-tetris-game/

```
bool isValidGridPos() {        
     foreach (Transform child in transform) {
         Vector2 v = Grid.roundVec2(child.position);

         // Not inside Border?
         if (!Grid.insideBorder(v))
             return false;

         // Block in grid cell (and not part of same group)?
         if (Grid.grid[(int)v.x, (int)v.y] != null &&
             Grid.grid[(int)v.x, (int)v.y].parent != transform)
             return false;
     }
     return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The function is really easy to understand. At first it loops through every child by using foreach, then it stores the child's rounded position in a variable. Afterwards it finds out if that position is inside the border, and then it finds out if there already is a block in the same grid entry or not.

In other words – every time a shape is moved or rotated, you have to check if that position was valid.

You do that by checking that the position of the shape is within the bounds and that the shape isn't intersecting with any other shapes.

If it is out of bounds or intersecting with other shapes you revert your last action.

Action: `transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);`

Revert: `transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);`

```
// Rotate
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);

// See if valid
if (isValidGridPos())
    // It's valid. Update grid.
    updateGrid();
else
    // It's not valid. revert.
    transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);
}
```

Comment: thanks you for your explaination. The rest of the code is very clearly, but this line still get me confused. Grid.grid[(int)v.x, (int)v.y].parent != transform.

Comment: The tutorial explains it. This is an edge case that allows shapes within the same transform to ignore the check and collide with each other.

Comment: does this line : Grid.grid[(int)v.x, (int)v.y].parent != transform mean that check parent's property whether equal to child's transform or not ?

Answer (score 0):

That function is very easy. The bool isValidGridPos checks if all Child in a Group are Valid to move for example.

```
bool isValidGridPos() {        
    foreach (Transform child in transform) { // Loop through all childs
        Vector2 v = Grid.roundVec2(child.position); //Get the position as Int (rounded number or floored number)

        // Not inside Border?
        if (!Grid.insideBorder(v)) // Checks if the Position is in the Game
            return false;

        // Block in grid cell (and not part of same group)?
        if (Grid.grid[(int)v.x, (int)v.y] != null &&
            Grid.grid[(int)v.x, (int)v.y].parent != transform)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```